# How to send Plain text body in email in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

My email is sending properly with subject name, now I dont know how to send email body with simple text. The thing just now I am doing is sending blank email with just a subject name on it.
Can anyone help me?

```
$data = array('title' => 'Forget Password - App', 'content' => 'This is the content of mail body');
           Mail::send(['text' => 'view'],$data, function ($message) {
                $message->from('fromemail@gmail.com', 'Social Team');
                $message->to('randomemail@gmail.com');
                $message->subject('App - Forget Password');
            });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `raw` method to send the plain text in mail.
Here is the example:

```
Mail::raw('This is the content of mail body', function ($message) {
    $message->from('fromemail@gmail.com', 'Social Team');
    $message->to('randomemail@gmail.com');
    $message->subject('App - Forget Password');
});
```

Comment: Ty and now If I want to send a link with text somthing your password is link is this...then I can replace with a variable having link in it will it work?

Comment: @JayminNoob it's better to use a view and pass variables to it while sending mails.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in the mail send `['text' => 'view']` means you want to send plain text email with template 'view'. So you need to create the view template resources/views/view.blade.php

In that view template you can use the data that you assign to the template. E.g.

```
{{ $title }}
some text
{{ $content }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use send method and setBody with plain text or html.

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
  $message->to(..)
    ->subject(..)
    // here comes what you want
    ->setBody('Hi, welcome user!'); // assuming text/plain
    // or:
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1><br> hello world', 'text/html'); // for HTML rich messages.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Write your email like this

```
Mail::send('email.email', array('msg' => $txtmsg), function ($message)use($data) {
//content of email send
}
```

Important thing is to use this in your view which is email blade template
`{!! $msg !!}`
I am just passing raw html to the view.